# Put a object from Material Design Dialog into main controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

I have an application that allows the user to create and edit records in a modal Angular Material Design Dialog  ($mdDialog)
My problem is to put the object returned by the dialog into a collecion that is in the main controller. Is there a way to do that?

```
angular.module("module").controller("mainController", function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.Users = [];

    function OpenEditWindow(userToEdit) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'Views/user.html',
            controller: 'UserDialogController',
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            locals: { // Envia valores para o controller do dialog
                User: userToEdit
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
            // Put the object edited into the collection on main controller, to show on the screen
            $scope.Users.push(data); // ******** NOT WORKS
        });
    }
});

angular.module('module')
.controller('UserDialogController', function ($scope, $mdDialog, User) {
    $scope.User = User;

    $scope.Save = function () {
        $mdDialog.hide($scope.User);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can centralize your data and create a service model that persists the state of your user across your application. Such a service can be passed into your controller like every other dependency.

```
angular.module('module')
.controller('UserDialogController', function ($scope, $mdDialog, User, UserModel) {
    $scope.User = User;

    $scope.Save = function () {
        $mdDialog.hide($scope.User);
    }
});


angular.module('module').factory('UserModel', function () {

    var userModel = this;

    userModel.set = function(){
     ...
    }

    return userModel;
});
```

Given that services are singletons you are guaranteed to have access to the latest and greatest information every time.

Try using a style guide which will greatly improve your code, logic and overall quality. Such a guide could be [John Papa's Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Answer (score 0):

What is returned from `$mdDialog.show` is a promise. You are putting your `then` in the wrong place. This is shown in the angular material docs [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)

```
angular.module("module").controller("mainController", function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.Users = [];

    function OpenEditWindow(userToEdit) {
        var promise = $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'Views/user.html',
            controller: 'UserDialogController',
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            locals: { // Envia valores para o controller do dialog
                User: userToEdit
            }
        });

        promise.then(function (data) {
            // Put the object edited into the collection on main controller, to show on the screen
            $scope.Users.push(data); // ******** NOT WORKS
        });
    }
});
```